# Editable Fields, Custom Submit function is not being called?

Tags: 7, forms

I'm using editable fields, so I can edit the fields on node display page (e.g. at node/123). I want to add a submit function, so that I can add other process every time the user edit the field. My problem is my custom submit function is not being called.

Below is the code I'm using:

```
function apws_extras_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  switch ($form_id) {
    case 'editablefields_form_node_field_apws_batch_completed_field':
      if ($form['type']['#value'] == 'apws_batch') {
        $form['#validate'][] = 'apws_extras_batch_completed_form_validate';
        $form['#submit'][] = 'apws_extras_batch_completed_form_submit';
      }
      break;
  }
}

function apws_extras_batch_completed_form_validate(&$form, &$form_state){
  // Check if this field is set.
  // Code for validation here.
}

function apws_extras_batch_completed_form_submit(&$form, &$form_state) {
  drupal_set_message('Submit is working');
}
```

[image]

Comment: Please provide a sample code how you're trying to add a custom submit handler, that will help find the issue and provide better solution.

Comment: Hi @yogesh, I have edited the body and added the code.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
function apws_extras_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
    switch ($form_id) {
case 'editablefields_form_node_field_apws_batch_completed_field':
      if ($form['type']['#value'] == 'apws_batch') {
        $form['#validate'][] = 'apws_extras_batch_completed_form_validate';
        //$form['#submit'][] = 'apws_extras_batch_completed_form_submit';
        $form['actions']['submit']['#submit'][] = 'apws_extras_batch_completed_form_submit';
      }
      break;
  }
}

function apws_extras_batch_completed_form_validate(&$form, &$form_state){
  // Check if this field is set.
  // Code for validation here.
}

function apws_extras_batch_completed_form_submit(&$form, &$form_state) {
  drupal_set_message('Submit is working');
}
```

Comment: // Attach our custom submit handler.
      $form['actions']['publish']['#submit'][] ='my_module_node_article_form_submit';

Comment: Hi @atikrant, it still not working. :(

Comment: @MarvinLaton: Have checked by clearing drupal cache? Still it is not working then print the '$form' and post your array here.

Comment: Yes I have clear cache but the submit handler is not working. I have edited the body and attached the screenshot the array of the $form.

Comment: @MarvinLaton: EditableFields module is having bugs. Please apply patch for that module and then check.

Comment: This is correct due to `form_execute_handlers()` ignoring the form level submit handlers because there is a button's submit handler on the form.  I've tested this manually and it works.
`$form['actions']['submit']['#submit'][]` is the right way to add another button submit handler.